# Why is this code not dynamically setting the groupbox control anchor property?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

> Here is the code:

```
Private WithEvents modderInfoGroup As New NSGroupBox
modderInfoGroup.Text = ""
modderInfoGroup.Location = New Point(3, 3)
modderInfoGroup.Size = New Size(512, 424)
modderInfoGroup.DrawSeperator = True
modderInfoGroup.Title = currentModder
modderInfoGroup.SubTitle = "Modder Information"
modderInfoGroup.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top Or AnchorStyles.Left Or AnchorStyles.Bottom Or AnchorStyles.Right
myTabPage.Controls.Add(modderInfoGroup)
myTabPage.Name = "modder" & modderNumber
```

When creating the Control dynamically is defaults to Top and Left but i want it to set it to all 4 edges. Anyone got a fix?

This is a Windows Form(WinForm) in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Maybe you should just `modderInfoGroup.Dock = DockStyle.Fill` instead.  If you want to use anchors for all sides, then the Size would have to be set to the ClientSize of the TabPage.

Comment: `AnchorStyles.Top And AnchorStyles.Left And AnchorStyles.Bottom And AnchorStyles.Right`. I think it should be **And** instead of **Or**

Comment: @LarsTech explain the clientSize

Comment: Don't ignore the Dock = Fill option I offered.  For the anchors to work in your scenario, set the size to the client container: `modderInfoGroup.Size = MyTabPage.ClientSize`  Either set the location to 0, 0 or modify that size by making the groupbox size 6 pixels smaller for the width and height.

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks. I used the dock option. Put it in an answer for me though.

Comment: @FarhanAnam It's `OR`.  Look inside a Designer.vb file of a form that has a control's Anchor properties set.

Comment: thnx for 'enlightening' me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to fill the space of the container control, then the property you want to set is the Dock property:

```
modderInfoGroup.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
```

The anchor property was working, but the initial size didn't match the size of the client area of the parent control.  To make that work, you would have to set the size to that client size:

```
modderInfoGroup.Location = Point.Empty
modderInfoGroup.Size = MyTabPage.ClientSize
```